# Creating wavy pipe lip

Tags: modeling

[image: Wavy pipe lip]

I need to create a wavy pipe lip just as this image shows. I'm not
referring to the corrugated side, just the top lip. And the lip
surface must be smooth. Is there a tool in Blender that would allow
me to do this?

Comment: This looks like a simple matter of booleans.

Comment: I can boolean cut ovals but that won't get me a continuously smooth surface all around

Comment: give it a few moments and @Chris will bring his geometry nodes ;)

Comment: I  try ;) .......

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Classic way ...

- Add Cylinder 8 sides (octagon)

[image]

- in Edit mode select two opposite vertices and move upward 0.2 and in two in cross direction downward -0.2

[image]

- add Subsurf and Solidify modifier

[image]

[image]

---

Same can be done with *Surface* object > **NURBS Cylinder**

Comment: I was about to try making 2 sine waves and putting the sample into the screw modifier. Your solution seems much better.

Answer (score 16):

**UPDATE**

Ok, here in smooth, fully procedural and non destructive:

[image]

result:

[image]

[image]

---

You can get this:

[image]

by this node group:

[image]

but better use this:

[image]

to get this:

[image]

changing the sin input value you can adjust:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's definitely impressive functionality and I'm going to end up using that in the future. But the lip must be smooth and not segmented. Is this possible with the solution you've provided?

Comment: thank you very much! I updated my answer. It is now smooth and it is non destructive - you can change it without effort.

Comment: I never used geometry nodes before. I don't get the meaning of the multiply nodes on the left. Wouldn't "Multiply 0.02" and "Multiply 3.2" combine to a single "Multiply 0.064"?

Comment: Of course. But if you ever tried to slide a low value with the mouse, you would recognize that it is very difficult to change it because although you hold shift it still changes too fast. That’s why I added a second multiply node.

Answer (score 5):

### Blender 3.0.

I would say those geonoodles are kosher, but I'm not sure it'd be politically correct so I won't say so.

[image]

[image] [image]

Note:

- Curve samples should be a multiple of humps
- Catmull-Clark Subdivision smooths the shape and lowers the tips (Hump height is not accurate)

Comment: Hehe.. this is almost identical to the answer I didn't post :D

Comment: @RobinBetts I actually colored my frames inspired by your setups.